# Symbolically access object created by getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

In the following pseudo-code, I don't know how to identify ?unknown?. I realize that y has the name of the symbol pointed to by asset. The objects for the symbols are stored in the environment. I need to access the object through a variable.

```
library(quantmod)
x<-c("IBM","GOOG","AAPL")  
for (asset in x)  
{  
    y <- getSymbols(asset, src = "yahoo",from = startDate,to = endDate,auto.assign=FALSE)  
    mydf <- convert ?unknown? to data frame        
    mydf$time <- time(?unknown?)  

    #process mydf  
    #store results in another data frame  

}  
#display results
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new environnment where I store the variables.

```
library(quantmod)
x<-c("IBM","GOOG","AAPL")  
e = new.env()
getSymbols(x, src = "yahoo",from = startDate,
           to = endDate,auto.assign=FALSE,env=e)
```

Then to process variable inside the new environment you can use `eapply` :

```
mydf <- eapply(e,function(asset){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

With `auto.assign=F` they are not assigned to an environment variable (that is a behavior that will be deprecated). Now you get an object of class "xts". You can just do

```
library(quantmod)
startDate <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2014-01-10")
x<-c("IBM","AAPL")  
dfall<-NULL
for (asset in x)  
{  
    y <- getSymbols(asset, src = "yahoo",
        from = startDate,to = endDate,auto.assign=FALSE)  
    mydf <- as.data.frame(y)
    names(mydf)<-c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
    mydf$symbol <- asset
    mydf$time <- time(y)  

    if(is.null(dfall)) {
        dfall<-mydf
    } else {
        dfall<-rbind(dfall, mydf)
    }

}
dfall
```